# Sudo-apt update giving me errors?

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager, 20.10

I am a new user and I am having trouble working around this issue. When I sudo-apt update, I get the error:

```
<pre>Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease                     
Ign:2 http://ddebs.ubuntu.com groovy-updates InRelease                         
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76/pop/ubuntu groovy InRelease            
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security InRelease            
Ign:5 http://ddebs.ubuntu.com groovy-security InRelease             <font color="#C4A000">           </font>
Hit:6 http://apt.pop-os.org/proprietary groovy InRelease            
Hit:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates InRelease  
Ign:8 http://ddebs.ubuntu.com groovy-proposed InRelease<font color="#C4A000">             </font>
Hit:9 https://repo.nordvpn.com//deb/nordvpn/debian stable InRelease 
Hit:10 http://ddebs.ubuntu.com groovy-updates Release<font color="#C4A000">               </font>
Hit:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-backports InRelease
Err:12 http://ddebs.ubuntu.com groovy-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.94.8 80]
Hit:13 http://ddebs.ubuntu.com groovy-proposed Release
Err:14 http://ddebs.ubuntu.com groovy-updates Release.gpg
  The following signatures couldn&apos;t be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C8CAB6595FDFF622
Err:15 http://ddebs.ubuntu.com groovy-proposed Release.gpg
  The following signatures couldn&apos;t be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C8CAB6595FDFF622
Reading package lists... Done
<font color="#CC0000"><b>E: </b></font>The repository &apos;http://ddebs.ubuntu.com groovy-security Release&apos; does not have a Release file.
<font color="#C4A000">N: </font>Updating from such a repository can&apos;t be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
<font color="#C4A000">N: </font>See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
<font color="#C4A000"><b>W: </b></font>An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://ddebs.ubuntu.com groovy-updates Release: The following signatures couldn&apos;t be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C8CAB6595FDFF622
<font color="#C4A000"><b>W: </b></font>An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://ddebs.ubuntu.com groovy-proposed Release: The following signatures couldn&apos;t be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C8CAB6595FDFF622
</pre>
```

What can I do to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: There may (probably) be other errors, but those font color things should not be in there.  Did you edit your sources list by cutting and pasting from a web page? You also appear to be using Pop OS, which is off topic here.

Comment: Follow the [last two commands in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/508337/167115) (making sure to substitute C8CAB6595FDFF622 for the key) to fix the no pubkey error and then update your question if you still have errors. Thanks.

Comment: i apologize, i am relatively new and just thought bc its Ubuntu based. the only thing i have done since install is install snap store.

Comment: thank you, mchid. your solution worked.